# Automatic href Link click

Tags: php, html

Hai
i want to generated an automated click event. I am working in php server, i Know Javascript.
Below is my Code

```
<script language="javascript">

function autoClick() {
var elm=document.getElementById('thisLink');
    elm.click();
     document.getElementById('thisLink').click();
    }

</script>
</head>
```

i put this on inside the `body` tag :

```
onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',3000);"
```

and inside the `a` tag :

```
href="./apage.php" id="thisLink" name="thisLink" target="newWindow"
```

But it doesn't work in MOzilla Is  any solution , 0r any other solution ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it works when you manually click on the link?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" exactly, and install firebug and see what it tells you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try JQuery's trigger function.

```
$('#thisLink').trigger('click');
```

This should possibly work although I haven't tested it.

JQuery: http://jquery.com

doc: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger#eventdata

Comment: Did the OP ask for a jquery solution? No? Then you need to provide *both*.

Comment: OP stands for »original poster«

Answer (score 1):

[Element.click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click) works **only on input elements** on Mozilla. Try something like

```
function autoClick() {
  var elm=document.getElementById('thisLink');
  document.location.href = elm.href;
}
```

instead, or if you prefer opening the link into a new window,

```
function autoClick() {
  var elm=document.getElementById('thisLink');
  window.open(elm.href, 'autoclickwindow');
}
```

Comment: But this wouldn't open the window in a new tab.